# Scala: Is ForComprehension a Functional approach or imperative?

Tags: scala

My collections:

```
val l1 = List(1, 2, 3)
val l2 = List("A", "B", "C")
```

Here is an imperative approach:

```
for {
    e1 <- l1
    e2 <- l2
  } {
    println(s"$e1 - $e2")
  }
```

And FP approach:

```
l1 foreach { 
  a => l2 foreach { 
    b => println { 
      s"$a - $b" 
    } 
  } 
}
```

However, classic `for` loop represents a purely imperative style, I have some doubts about imperativeness of `For Comprehension` loop. So my question is: am I right that `For Comprehension` loop is from imperative style or not?

Comment: I don't think the question makes sense. `for (...) yield { ... }` is functional, since it produces a new value. `for (...) { }` is imperative, since it does a side effect. Both are for comprehensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A for-comprehension is a functional way of writing "imperative-looking" code.

I'll cite Paul Chiusano and Runar Bjarnason from "Functional Programming in Scala" because I could never put it better:

Page 89

> **Aren’t imperative and functional programming opposites?**
>
> Absolutely not. Remember, functional programming is simply programming without
>   side effects. Imperative programming is about programming with statements that
>   modify some program state, and as we’ve seen, it’s entirely reasonable to maintain
>   state without side effects.
>
> Functional programming has excellent support for writing imperative programs, with
>   the added benefit that such programs can be reasoned about equationally because
>   they’re referentially transparent.

---

An example from the same page:

```
val ns: Rand[List[Int]] =
  int.flatMap(x =>
    int.flatMap(y =>
      ints(x).map(xs =>
        xs.map(_ % y))))
```

> It’s not clear what’s going on here. But since we have `map` and `flatMap` defined, we can
>   use a for-comprehension to recover the imperative style:

```
val ns: Rand[List[Int]] = for {
  x <- int
  y <- int
  xs <- ints(x)
} yield xs.map(_ % y)
```

> This code is much easier to read (and write), and it looks like what it is—an imperative
>   program that maintains some state. But it’s the same code. We get the next `Int` and
>   assign it to `x`, get the next `Int` after that and assign it to `y`, then generate a list of length
>   `x`, and finally return the list with all of its elements modulo `y`.
>    To facilitate this kind of imperative programming with for-comprehensions (or
>   `flatMaps`), we really only need two primitive State combinators—one for reading the
>   state and one for writing the state.

---

One more from page 203:

> We can see that a chain of `flatMap` calls (or an equivalent
>   for-comprehension) is like an imperative program with statements that assign to variables,
>   and *the monad specifies what occurs at statement boundaries*.

Comment: Ok, so the difference not between Functional/Imperative styles, but in a way we represent the loop code (specific, in my example). Am I right?

Comment: @Finkelson Well, in your examples, neither approach is functional, because they invoke `println` which has side effects.

Comment: @Finkelson But *if* you replaced `println(s"$e1 - $e2")` with `yield e1 + e2`, and `foreach` with `flatMap`/`map` (to remove the side-effects) then you could say that the first approach is functional and imperative, whereas the second is functional, but not imperative.